# python ftplib transfercmd() BINARY Mode

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, ftp

in the absence of an answer to my previous question.

I am using multihtreading to keep a large FTP transfer alive via the control socket.

Unfortuantely this requires the use of ftplib.ftp.transfercmd() (rather than FTP.retrbinary() which does not give explicit socket control) which returns the data socket exclusively and allows you to send 'NOOP' commands without blocking.

This is a problem as transfercmd("RETR" ...) defaults to dwonloading in ASCII mode which corrupts the video files I'm trying to download.

I have scoured everything Ican to find an explicit BINARY mode command to no avail. Any ideas?

heres is my download code

```
def downloadFile(filename, folder):
    #login
    ftp = FTP(myhost,myuser,passw)
    ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
    sock = ftp.transfercmd('RETR ' + filename)
    def background():
        f = open(folder + filename, 'wb')
        while True:
            block = sock.recv(1024*1024)
            if not block:
                break
            f.write(block)
        sock.close()
    t = threading.Thread(target=background)
    t.start()
    while t.is_alive():
        t.join(60)
        ftp.voidcmd('NOOP')
```

Comment: You most likely didn't see my [second comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703379/python-ftplib-handbrake-unrecognized-file-type?noredirect=1#comment29268611_19703379) on your other post.

Comment: hi @plg. I saw your second comment, but unfortunately you didnt read either post properly. I am prevented from using RETRBINARY as I need to explicity access to the data socket and only transfercmd gives you that

Comment: Oh, sorry I hadn't looked at ftplib's source, and assumed it also returned a socket. What I'd suggest is you have a look at how `FTP.transfercmd()` actually opens the socket and extend the class to override the method. [src](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/ftplib.py#l374) `ntrasfercmd()` is right above so just scroll up a bit.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had actually just explicitly sent a voidcmd("TYPE I") to force binary, which is esstially what I would have done in extending the ftp lib. so you are spot on! If you answer the question I will upvote and accept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `retrbinary()`'s [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/ftplib.py#l399) suggests you have to tell the FTP server you want binary with the `TYPE I` command:

```
ftp.voidcmd('TYPE I')
# Do the transfer here
```

`retrbinary` actually does the transfer for you, but doesn't seem to update the connection to keep it from closing.

Also you don't need a thread, just put ftp.voidcmd('NOOP') in the download loop:

```
def downloadFile(filename, folder):
    #login
    ftp = FTP(myhost,myuser,passw)
    ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
    ftp.voidcmd('TYPE I')
    sock = ftp.transfercmd('RETR ' + filename)
    f = open(folder + filename, 'wb')
    while True:
        block = sock.recv(1024*1024)
        if not block:
            break
        ftp.voidcmd('NOOP')
        f.write(block)
    sock.close()
```